# Turn all unique values of a column into a set or array in a returned column of a GROUPY BY query

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregation

I have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) count, userid, displaydate 
FROM data 
GROUP BY userid, displaydate 
HAVING COUNT(userid) > 1
```

I would like to modify this to include another column, `type` so that I could create an array of all the unique `type` values that occur per group. So for example if I have some data like this:

```
userid, displaydate, type
a,      1242242422,   0
a,      1242242422,   1
```

How could I get the following returned:

```
(a, 1242242422, [0, 1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `array_agg`.

```
SELECT userid, displaydate, array_agg(distinct type)
-- use array_agg(distinct type order by type) if the type needs to be ordered
FROM data 
GROUP BY userid, displaydate 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Because of "_all the unique type_" `array_agg(distinct type)` I think.